# Get the line that the function was called at?

Tags: php, function, line, call

I've looked this up and I know that the answer probably involves the use of [`debug_backtrace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php), but I am struggling on how to use it or exactly what it does.

Basically, if this was index.php:

```
<?php
//some code
//some more code

require "functions.php";

print_line();

//some code

print_line();
?>
```

and functions.php was:

```
<?php
function print_line(){
    $line="[line that this function was called at]";
    print "This function was called from line $line of index.php<br />";
}
?>
```

What would be the correct way of setting `$line` so that the output would be:

```
This function was called from line 7 of index.php
This function was called from line 11 of index.php
```

Comment: Have you tried to run `debug_backtrace` before asking? What did it's output tell you?

Answer (score 14):

**debug_backtrace()** contains all nested function calls all the way to the current scope indexing from 0 (the closest).

So when you need the line where **print_line()** was called, just go with:

```
<?php
function print_line(){
    $backtrace = debug_backtrace();

    $line=$backtrace[0]['line'];
    print "This function was called from line $line of index.php<br />";
}
```

Or as of PHP 5.4:

```
$line=debug_backtrace()[0]['line'];
```

Comment: I always prefer this approach as you do not have to pass the line/file around and making the functions less depended, having to deal with less arguments and they are more compact where called.

Comment: That's cool, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code below to get the current line, just pass it in as a parameter to your print_line() function

```
print_line(__line__);
```

Comment: Thanks - but although that would work, I would prefer a way of doing it which didn't involve passing it as a parameter, because then if I were to change the code I would have to change all the function calls to that function.